# Cordova Android Config

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-android

I am working on a Cordova app and trying to change values in the cdv-gradle-condig.json
but it keeps return to default whenever i run the app from command line:

```
cordova run android
```

Especcially I am trying to update the AGP_VERSION as it seems to be the app gradle's plugin version

```
{
 "MIN_SDK_VERSION": 22,
 "SDK_VERSION": 30,
 "GRADLE_VERSION": "7.1.1",
 "MIN_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION": "30.0.3",
 "AGP_VERSION": "4.2.2", <--//How can I change this??
 "KOTLIN_VERSION": "1.6.10",
 "ANDROIDX_APP_COMPAT_VERSION": "1.3.1",
 "ANDROIDX_WEBKIT_VERSION": "1.4.0",
 "GRADLE_PLUGIN_GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION": "4.3.8",
 "IS_GRADLE_PLUGIN_GOOGLE_SERVICES_ENABLED": false,
 "IS_GRADLE_PLUGIN_KOTLIN_ENABLED": true
}

dependencies {
   // Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) Build Tools
   classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:${cordovaConfig.AGP_VERSION}"
}
```

In addition, I also try to update gradle distribution url from gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip
```

If I change the values manually and run the app from AndroidStudio it stays, but from command line it just returns to default and the build fails!

Comment: I have to update the AGP version. how to update it from config.xml.

Answer (score 5):

The AGP version or AndroidGooglePlugin can be specified in config.xml through AndroidGradlePluginVersion preference. i.e:

```
 <preference name="AndroidGradlePluginVersion" value="7.2.2" />
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

edit cdv-gradle-config-defaults.json

in

cordova/node_modules/cordova-android/framework/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @ahmad apandi I don't think it's a good idea to edit files inside node_modules